# Is Rygate, Surry the same as Reigate, Surrey?

Tags: england, historical-gazetteer, place-names, maps

One of my possible ancestors is from "Rygate, England".  Googling that shows "Reigate, Surrey".  When I force searches for "Rygate" it shows old references to places like Rygate Cathedral in Surry, and "An Exact List of All the Fairs in England and Wales" listing one in Rygate, Surry.

So... it *seems* like *Rygate, Surry* is just an archaic form of *Reigate, Surrey*, but names in England can get confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a spelling variation, similar to that encountered at [What does Orring County North Carolina mean in Quaker records?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13501/6485)

You have already found a wealth of evidence that the Rygate, Surry and Reigate, Surrey are the same place (by locating identically or very similarly named features in both places.). However, finding Rygate or a similar variant spelling on a map in a location would be the final proof.

At [OldMapsOnline](http://www.oldmapsonline.org) you'll find a number of maps of various vintages that show Rygate or Reygate or Ryegate congruent with modern Reigate.